# how to convert string timestamp from gregorian to shamsi

Tags: android

hello i'am getting a timestamp from server in gregorian what look likes this

```
{
  "error": false,
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "dfsg",
      "active": 1,
      "created_at": "2017-02-14 00:13:25"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "asf",
      "active": 1,
      "created_at": "2017-02-14 13:42:26"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "username": "test2",
      "active": 1,
      "created_at": "2017-02-15 13:57:31"
    }
  ]
}
```

and i want to change it to shamsi  what should look like this
1395-11-26 13:42:26 
is there any class to do it ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time)

As such:

```
        Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC();
        Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC();

        LocalDate todayIso = new LocalDate(2013, 3, 31, iso);
        LocalDate todayHijri = new LocalDate(todayIso.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(),
                                             hijri);
        System.out.println(todayHijri); // 1434-05-19
```

To get the year, month and day from your string use the following:

```
String startDateString = "2017-02-14 00:13:25";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = df.parse(startDateString);
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);

int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
//Add one to month {0 - 11}
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: ty @zed but it's for hijri and i need shamsi Conversion

Comment: Aah excuse me, I read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar and thought Shamsi is Hijri. Are you sure it isn't the same?

Comment: yes sir hijri is arabic and shamsi is for persians thank in advance

Comment: Updated answer to get year month and day from string.

Comment: oh your so king dear zed :x but date.getYear is decepreted and it returns value like 117 but you can pass date to a Calendar and  and get year from Calendar . you can again update your answer maybe help some one . sry if my reputation is under 15 and i cant give you +1

Answer (score 2):

you could add this class in your project, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377219/gregorian-to-hijri-islamic-date)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class PersianDate {
    public String todayShamsi() 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String curentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        String year = curentDateandTime.substring(0, 4);
        String month = curentDateandTime.substring(4, 6);
        String day = curentDateandTime.substring(6, 8);
        int Y = Integer.valueOf(year);
        int M = Integer.valueOf(month);
        int D = Integer.valueOf(day);
        return Shamsi(Y, M, D);
    }
    public static String Shamsi(int Y, int M, int D)
    {
        if (Y == 0)
            Y = 2000;
        if (Y < 100)
            Y = Y + 1900;
        if (Y == 2000)
        {
            if (M > 2)
            {
                SimpleDateFormat temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                String curentDateandTime = temp.format(new Date());
                String year = curentDateandTime.substring(0, 4);
                String month = curentDateandTime.substring(4, 6);
                String day = curentDateandTime.substring(6, 8);
                Y = Integer.valueOf(year);
                M = Integer.valueOf(month);
                D = Integer.valueOf(day);
            }
        }
        if (M < 3 || (M == 3 && D < 21))
        {
            Y -= 622;
        }
        else Y -= 621;
        switch (M)
        {
        case 1: if (D < 21)
        {
            M = 10;
            D = D + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            M = 11;
            D -= 20;
        }
        break;
        case 2: if (D < 20)
        {
            M = 11;
            D = D + 11;
        }
        else
        {
            M = 12;
            D -= 19;
        }
        break;
        case 3:
            if (D < 21)
            {
                M = 12;
                D = D + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                M = 1;
                D -= 20;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (D < 21)
            {
                M = 1;
                D = D + 11;
            }
            else
            {
                M = 2; D = D - 20;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (D < 22)
            {
                M = M - 3;
                D = D + 10;
            }
            else
            {
                M = M - 2;
                D = D - 21;
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            if (D < 22)
            {
                M = M - 3;
                D = D + 10;
            }
            else
            {
                M = M - 2;
                D = D - 21;
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if (D < 23)
            {
                M = M - 3;
                D = D + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                M = M - 2;
                D = D - 22;
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            if (D < 23)
            {
                M = M - 3;
                D = D + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                M = M - 2;
                D = D - 22;
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            if (D < 23)
            {
                M = M - 3;
                D = D + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                M = M - 2;
                D = D - 22;
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            if (D < 23)
            {
                M = 7;
                D = D + 8;
            }
            else
            {
                M = 8;
                D = D - 22;
            }
            break;
        case 11:
            if (D < 22)
            {
                M = M - 3;
                D = D + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                M = M - 2;
                D = D - 21;
            }
            break;
        case 12:
            if (D < 22)
            {
                M = M - 3;
                D = D + 9;
            }
            else
            {
                M = M - 2;
                D = D - 21;
            }
            break;
        }
        String month = "00";
        String day = "00";
        //D = Integer.valueOf(D)+1;
        if (M < 10)
        {
            month = "0" + M;
        }
        else
        {
            month = String.valueOf(M);
        }
        if (D < 10)
        {
            day = "0" + D;
        }
        else
        {
            day = String.valueOf(D);
        }
        return String.valueOf(Y) + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro its need 3 integer value as year and moth and day to retrun shamsi . how can i get this values from my string ?